# SimpleDateFormatter seems to be ignoring TimeZone

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, timezone, simpledateformat

I am trying to format a Calendar object to return the time in a specific format.
However, the SimpleDateFormatter is ignoring the TimeZone of Calendar obj and it's own TimeZone attribute and making unnecessary time conversion. My computer is in EST and I am passing the Calendar obj in "PST". The time passed in is:Tue Jan 14 10:28:49, I was expecting the return val as "10:28:49 AM PST". However the value, returned is "07:28:49 AM PST". Why is the timezone calc being done when the formatter obj is set to PST? Also, how to prevent the tz conversion from EST to PST?

Here is the code:

```
public static String formatDateToString(Calendar cal) {
        if (cal != null) {
            TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
            String tzId = tz.getID();**//"PST"**

            Date date = cal.getTime();
            String str = date.toString();**//"Tue Jan 14 10:28:49 EST 2014"**
            final SimpleDateFormat sdFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a zzz");

            sdFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzId));
            String calStr = sdFormatter.format(cal.getTime());**//"07:28:49 AM PST"**

            return calStr;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar#getTime()` is implemented as (Oracle JDK7)

```
public final Date getTime() {
    return new Date(getTimeInMillis());
}
```

so regardless of the `TimeZone` the `Calendar` has, the `Date` object will use the system's default when you invoke its `toString()` method.

EST is 3 hours ahead of PST.

---

From the comments in your code snippet,

```
String tzId = tz.getID();**//"PST"**
...
String str = date.toString();**//"Tue Jan 14 10:28:49 EST 2014"**
final SimpleDateFormat sdFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a zzz");

sdFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzId));
String calStr = sdFormatter.format(cal.getTime());**//"07:28:49 AM PST"**
```

Everything seems all right. You are formatting the time represented as `Tue Jan 14 10:28:49 EST 2014` as a `PST` value. The time itself is exactly the same. The representation is different.

If you don't want to show it as PST, leave out the `setTimeZone()` call.

Comment: What I wanted to know is how to prevent the tz conversion from EST to PST?

Comment: @Neeraj See my comment. Maybe I've misunderstood your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to change the **Timezone** without changing the **Date** figures would be [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) lib's `withZoneRetainFields()` of `DateTime` class:

```
 Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(cal);
 DateTime dtz = dt.withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.forID("US/Pacific"));

 System.out.println(dt.toString());     
 System.out.println(dtz.toString());
```

Though Calendar class would have your current instance in EST, you would get the same time-digits converted to PST (no self calculation).

**Output:**

```
2014-01-15T12:00:51.324+05:30
2014-01-15T12:00:51.324-08:00
```

More details [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Changing_TimeZone).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working the way it should.  If `date.toString();` is `"Tue Jan 14 10:28:49 EST 2014"`, then the time represented by `date` is indeed `7:28:49` in PST, or `10:28:49` in EST.  A `Date` variable represents a particular moment in time, not a particular set of values for hour, minute, second and timezone.

When you set the timezone in the `SimpleDateFormatter`, you're saying, "when we format this date, show the hours, minutes and seconds in PST, corresponding to whatever moment of time the date represents".  So, don't think of this as converting a time from EST to PST - think of it as outputting the hours, minutes and seconds for a particular *moment*, but doing it in accord with a particular timezone.